# What is the best solution for document archiving?

Tags: software-recommendation, document-management

I'm looking for a utility that helps me (and my colleagues) to archive documents in a systematic manner (Like Zeitgeist but permanent).

1. The utility have to clean-out old
   document from desktops and store
   them on a server (as automatic as
   possible and consistent) maybe from
   just a few locations (Document
   directory)
2. Documents shall be
   stored on cheap large media for many
   years to come - hard disk and
   file system maybe? Easy to maintain
   and manage for a small organization.
3. Documents have to be easy to find
   and restore

One systematic manner could be a directory-structure by year, month, user or user, year, month.  Its a plus if documents could be linked to a project, if documents could be search-able and if document could also be mail, IM-discussions not only OpenOffice traditional documents.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is Ubuntu-related.

Comment: It might be, if the asker is looking for a Linux-based document archiving solution - specifically Ubuntu. He doesn't mention any requirement to use Windows.

Comment: It is a valid question. See http://linuxappfinder.com/office/documentmanagement for a list of document management tools for Linux. One requirement that should stand out is the ability to understand formats such as PDF and ODT and index them automatically, find duplicates, etc.

Comment: Well, we have an Ubuntu environment with Ubuntu-clients and servers, so I think this is Ubuntu related. I'm avare of several traditional document management systems. I have tested Knowledgeware, Alfresco, Drupal and OpenERP. But none of them operates on the desktop (and automaticly archive documents like Backintime, Deja-Dup, UbuntuOne, pam_csync and DropBox does for backup and directory synchronisation). A traditional DMS could be the storageplatform combined with a client that does the "clean-ups" and moves documents that are old enough for archive to the storage.

Comment: The downside with a DMS as storage is that it rapidly grows "old" in the archive perspective. DMSes comes with new releases several times during a decade and need a lot of love and migration work when you compare with a simple filesystem. Maybe a fileserver + indexserver (eg Solr) and Zeitgeist on the client whould do the work?

Comment: @Anders Can you add the things you've tried and all that relevant information to your question so it doesn't get buried in the comments? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can dedicate an old PC (with big new HDD/s) as a backup server and install [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/)

- No client-side software is needed - just export via NFS backup dirs on the clients (for example /home/ or /home/username/Desktop etc.) or share folders on Windows stations
- A powerful web user interface allows administration, view log files, configuration
- file extensions can be defined for including / excluding files
- uses rsync for fast backup

separately you can implement web search on the linux server using [Xapian](http://xapian.org/) or [Omega](http://xapian.org/docs/omega/overview.html)

Comment: Can I configure BackupPC for moving files to the archive? Usually a backup is a mirror of a state of a bunch of files. What I want is the process of archive files of an certain age to a filestore.

Comment: Xapian/omega sounds interesting I think Drupal has a search api for xapian and faceted search. I googled somthing about Zeitgeist and a xapian plugin - is this a solution to search the central archive the same way local search are done? Is it possible to preserve read permissions and groups when indexing with Xapian? Is teamgeist-extension for Zeitgeist some sort of indexserver for an enterprise?

Comment: I have googled for the combination of BackupPC and Xapian and found nothing. It seems that BackupPC stores documemt compressed, can Xapian index those compressed files?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cloud computing services like [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or [UbuntuOne](http://one.ubuntu.com)

I advise you tu use Dropbox, you can choose between free(2gb+8by invites other people) or paid plan (50 or 100gb).

You can share folders with other dropbox user or in read only way with anyone.

And restore deleted files

Comment: Well, I have concern about security, cost and capacity using this type of services. For instance this means that all employees home directories on all devices has to be several TB large. For security reasons the cloud service has to offer encrypted storage. I don't think Dropbox or UbuntuOne can compete with cheap large disks in costeffectiveness. If local disk was not a problem rsync/backup-pc, back-in-time or deja-dup to a server would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not based on Ubuntu, the museum I work for has evaluated [Archivista](http://www.archivista.ch/) . It's a software suite for storing, cataloging and indexing (and, if necessary, scanning and OCRing) documents that is available as a (somewhat non-standard) live CD called "[Archivista BOX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/archivista/)" (it's open source), but the company mainly sells appliances running the software. The catalog provides a web frontend.

They claim that the formats used are entirely open, documented and strive for longevity. I must add that I personally have not evaluated that in great detail, though.

Comment: My german is a little rusty. There is a chapter about archiving  http://www.archivista.ch/de/pages/produkte/dms-und-erp/dms-und-archivierung.php
What is the general idea about archives? Do they use a separate indexserver? If it is, are there any connections to search utilies on the Gnome platform?
It seems that they convert documents to pdf and then store them in a fileserver (is this correct read?)

Comment: Just use http://www.archivista.ch/en/pages/products/dms-erp.php -- all pages seem to be available in English, too :-) The language selection link is in the blue menu box on the left, at the bottom.